# PowerShell search string and copy file

Tags: powershell

I'm preparing a script to find some text inside the files ('test' and 'test1' are the keywords in this scenario) and once all the files have been found, they should be copied to a different location while maintaining the folder structure.

For example:
The path c: \ src contains 10 files, 3 include the search words.
These 3 files should be copied to c: \ dst \

Everything should be recursive for all subdirectories of c: \ src.

So if in the path c: \ src \ somefolder \ there were other files with the same search words, they should be copied to c: \ dst \ somefolder \

Here my code:

```
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Note: Path must end with '\'"
Write-Host ""

# Var.
$sourceDir = Read-Host 'Source path'
$targetDir = Read-Host 'Destination path'

# Decl.
$tree = gci -Directory -Name -Recurse $sourceDir

# Check if $sourceDir exist
if(!(Test-Path -Path $sourceDir )){
  "Source is not a valid path!" ; pause
exit 1
}

# Check (and create) $targetDir
if(!(Test-Path -Path $targetDir )){
  mkdir $targetDir -Force
}

# Rebuild Tree
foreach ( $folders in $tree ) { mkdir $targetDir\$folders -Force }

# Copy Founded Files
$ftc = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse | Select-String "test","test2" | Select Path |
foreach{    
  $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length); 
  Copy-Item $_ -destination $targetFile
}
```

I can not figure out where the error is.
Does anyone know how I can solve it ?

The proposed error is: Copy-Item: Unable to find the unit. A unit named '@ {Path = C' does not exist.

Comment: What results are you expecting, and what results are you actually getting? Are you seeing any error messages? If so, what are they? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Well for beginners - You need to know the difference between [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) aliased as `gc` and [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) aliased as `gci`.
 
Like after getting the required files from `gci` cmdlet, you need to read that using the `gc` cmdlet and then pipe it to `Select-String`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh if I want to apply the proposed change to the code, you can show me how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: I see a problem only creating a fixed targetdir, since recursing sourcedir you wil have to check the resulting targetdir for every file.

Comment: @LotPings Unfortunately a copy error is proposed, from what I could understand it seems that the script can not find the path of the source file. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script had some severe bugs

- the `-Name` parameter in your gci building the tree only left the
  subdir Name so the rebuild tree part only had a flat structure the gci on files lateron can't match.
- your select-string pattern matches twice as the 2nd contains 1st, so I added the `-Unique` paramter to select Path
- used Get-Item $_.Path to build targetFile name pass to Copy-Item

This worked here on a (different) test tree:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\17\SO_50391092.ps1
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Note: Path must end with '\'"
Write-Host ""

# Var.
#$sourceDir = Read-Host 'Source path'
#$targetDir = Read-Host 'Destination path'
$sourceDir = "C:\test"
$targetDir = "A:\Test"

# Decl.
$tree = gci -Directory -Recurse $sourceDir

# Check if $sourceDir exist
if(!(Test-Path -Path $sourceDir )){
  "Source is not a valid path!" ; pause
  exit 1
}

# Check (and create) $targetDir
if(!(Test-Path -Path $targetDir )){mkdir $targetDir -Force}

# Rebuild Tree
foreach ( $folder in $tree ) {
    mkdir ($folder.fullname.replace($sourceDir,$targetDir)) -Force |Out-Null
}

# Copy Found Files
$ftc = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse | Select-String "test","test2" | Select -Unique Path |
foreach{
  $sourceFile = Get-Item $_.Path
  $targetFile = $sourceFile.Fullname.Replace($sourceDir,$targetDir)
  $sourceFile | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile
}
```